# FontAwesome not working after migration

Tags: wordpress, migration, font-awesome

We have a website built on wordpress with a theme that uses FontAwesome.

We are trying to migrate the site to a new server. On doing this, everything copied over perfectly except the FontAwesome icons are now just showing as squares.

See on our homepage on zealify.com where the "down chevron" is visible, whereas on the new server (162.13.82.19) it is not.

Any ideas as to why this might be the case? All help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are getting a 206 HTTP response, where the content is only partially loaded. This could be caused by a caching plugin but I can't be sure.

In your functions.php file, there should be a functions called `wp_enqueue_style()` that looks like so. You should note that your hook function is probably not called theme_name_scripts()

```
/**
 * Proper way to enqueue scripts and styles
 */
function theme_name_scripts() 
{
    // add this line
    wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' );
    // Example styles and scripts
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```

Or if you're lazy and don't care for good practice, you could add the following line to header.php to make it work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

[image: screenshot 1]

Comment: I'm not sure if adding that stylesheet would work in this case as the theme uses different class names for the icons?
Also, just did a quick browser test and can't seem to see any correlation - icons are showing in some but not in others - any ideas why?

Comment: That stylesheet is the font-awesome cdn, and these icons are font awesome. The reason for the different class names is because that is what they are called. And no you haven't added it, I just checked the source code.

Comment: Also, 206 means only some of the font-awesome file was loaded, hence why only some show up. Use the cdn to turn the 206 into a 200. thanks and good luck

Comment: Come to think of it, you may still need to change your url settings in Settings >> General

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. Added the link to header.php and it looks like it's working - thanks for your help @ham-sandwich, really appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution to my similar symptoms [here](https://time.ly/forums/topic/font-characters-not-displaying-after-migration/), from user Stuart Young.

Problem: After migration, the database is still set to load images and fonts from the *old* server. (Confirmed using devtools.) Webkit browsers like Chrome will happily ignore security best practices and go to the old server to fetch the requested resources. Other browsers (e.g., Firefox) will rightly refuse to load the fonts, and possibly the images as well.

Fix: Go to theme settings, change nothing, save, and it should rewrite the urls to match the current server. All efforts to fix the problem through the db were unsuccessful, but doing this solved the problem for me even though I'm using a completely different theme (Avada vs. Ai1ec).

Comment: This happened to me after migrating from Hostgator to Siteground. Everything showed up fine except the Fontawesome icons. In Wordpress simply go to "Theme Options" and click Save. (You might have to make one minor change, save, change back and save again, just to illuminate the Save button). Then go back to your site and do a hard refresh (Ctrl + F5). The FA icons should show back up.